# Android: save integer values on external storage

Tags: java, android, storage, inputstream, outputstream

I need help storing int values inside a text file and reading back from it. How is it done in android?

Comment: The same way it is done in Java, by writing and reading from a file. https://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=file+write+read+e&ix=sea&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=file+write+read+example+java

Comment: show us how you do it in another language

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.anddev.org/working_with_files-t115.html)

And you can use `DataInputStream`'s `readInt()` and `DataOutputStream`'s `writeInt()` methods.